# Make text item invisible of DropDownList-A when a item of DropDownList-B is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-events

Dropddown List A has 2 items, this DropddownList has no dependency on another dropdown list

Dropddown List B has 8 items, this DropddownList has dependency on DropddownList A

Items can be selected from Dropddown List B only if in Dropddown List A the selected item is Consultant

On the other hand, if in Dropddown List A the selected item is Company, no Item can be selected from Dropddown List B

This is the problem

Previously if an Item had already been selected in DropddownList B and the Item Company is selected in DropddownList A

causes that in DropddownList B it is not possible to select an Item but the Item that was selected before the change in DropddownList A is seen as selected in DropddownList B which should not be so.

That is the problem. Any advice is welcome

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ddListA = $('[id*=ddListA]');
        var ddListB = $('[id*=ddListB]');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (ddListA.val() == "Company") {
                ddListB.prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                ddListB.prop('disabled', false);
            }

            ddListA.change(function () {
                if (ddl.val() == "Company") {
                    ddListB.prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    ddListB.prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        });    


    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <hr>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <select id="ddListA" name="DropDownList A">
                <option value="none"> </option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>
                <option value="Consultant">Consultant</option>
              </select>
          </div>
        <hr>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <select id="ddListB" name="DropDownList B">
                <option value="none"> </option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="60">60</option>
                <option value="70">70</option>
                <option value="80">80</option>
              </select>
          </div>

        <hr>
        <br>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Issue:

[image: issue]

Design-dropdowns:

[image: design-dropdowns]

Comment: Where's the html? Can't debug front end using server side code

Comment: Also, do not tag `jQuery Validate` when the code has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Comment: it is a .aspx file, I just need help with the JavaScript the FrontEnd works fine

Comment: That asp file sends html to browser where the problem is. If you want help with the javascript you need to provide enough relevant html to run it with as per [mre]. It's not hard to copy from page source or browser dev tools

Comment: I just provided the suitable html to help me solve this problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectedIndex` to 0 like `prop("selectedIndex", 0).val()` to clear second drop down selection.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ddListA = $('[id*=ddListA]');
  var ddListB = $('[id*=ddListB]');
  if (ddListA.val() == "Company") {
    ddListB.prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    ddListB.prop('disabled', false);
  }

  ddListA.change(function() {
    if (ddListA.val() == "Company") {
      //ddListB.prop('disabled', true);
      ddListB.prop('disabled', true).prop("selectedIndex", 0).val();
    } else {
      ddListB.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <hr>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <select id="ddListA" name="DropDownList A">
      <option value="none"> </option>
      <option value="Company">Company</option>
      <option value="Consultant">Consultant</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <select id="ddListB" name="DropDownList B">
      <option value="none"> </option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
      <option value="70">70</option>
      <option value="80">80</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <br>

</div>
```

Comment: Shree, it works as I need your recommendation, thank you very much for the contribution !. Blessings

Comment: Glad to help :)